# PFSignupViewController Optional Email

Tags: ios, email, parse-platform

Is it possible to set the email field to be optional for the user to complete in PFSignUpViewController?

I was looking at the Apple App Store guidelines and they say the following in the privacy section;

"17.2 Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected"

If I force the user to enter an email address I'm concerned my app would be rejected.

I really don't want to create my own Signup and Login view controllers from scratch as I have just sub classed PFLoginViewController and PFSignUpViewController to get them how I'd like.

Thx.

Comment: Your app won't get rejected for asking the user to signup, if so, Facebook, Instagram, Twitter and Path would all be rejected from the App Store so don't worry.

Comment: Actually they do reject

Comment: Rejection happens when you ask the personal information for no reason. For example, if you have a clock app that asks for email, they will reject it because what's the point to provide and email address for a local app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting Parse docs:

> PFSignUpViewController can be configured to provide a variety of sign
> up options.

Here is the link: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-signup/iOS

So this code will just show user and password (not email):

```
signUpController.fields = (PFSignUpFieldsUsernameAndPassword);
```

There are more examples at the docs.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Did you test your solution?

Comment: No good solutions. I gave it to you anyways. Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ViewController: PFSignUpViewController, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.signUpView.emailField.placeholder = "E-Mail (Optional)"
    }

    func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController!, shouldBeginSignUp info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Bool {

        if info["password"] as String != "" && info["username"] as String != "" {
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }

    }
}
```